# putting two bytes together

Tags: c++, binary

I am reading a bytes from file. For this example, I read two bytes (represented in hexa)

`94` and `73`. How can I put these two bytes together, for them to look like

`9470` ?

I can use `73 >> 4` to make `70` out of `73` But how can i "put" them together?

I tried using `(94 << 8) & ( 73 >> 4 )` but it always returns 0.

I have found nothing about working with bytes like this. (Basicly reading one and half byte in this example), reading 2 bytes at once

code example

```
uint64_t bytes;
output.read( (char *)&bytes, 2 );  // read 2 bytes
uint64_t tmp       = ( cutIt  << ( 64 - 8) ) >> ( 64 - 8) ; 
uint64_t tmp_two   = (( cutIt >> 8) & 11110000 ) >> 4;
uint64_t tmp_three = (tmp << 8) & tmp_two ;
```

Comment: can you show the code.... there could be different ways ..

Comment: maybe you wanted to make `(94 << 8) | 73` which means shift first byte by 8 bits and make BITWISE OR with 73 (second byte)

Comment: this outputs 5e49 , not wanted result

Comment: @user3706129, not read it literaly. Ok, if you want exact thing: `((0x94<<8) | 74 ) & 0xFFF0`

Comment: `std::string f() { return "9470"; }` If you want something more sophisticated you have to more clearly specify what the rules are for combining values. The handwaving description in the question is pretty-much useless.

Answer (score 2):

```
((94 << 8)+74) & (FFF0)
```

will give you the output you want. for this you need to think binary.

```
((10010100 <<8) + 01110100) & (1111111111110000)
```

the 4 zeroes at the end will zero out your LSB thanks to the logical AND and maintain your word legth.

**To answer the commentqustion:** you simply chose the nuber of bits you want to use by changing the ammount of zeroes. For your example this would mean the number you use for the logical AND would be FFFC in hex or in binary
1111111111111100.

Comment: how would the code differ , if i wanted to load 1 byte and lets say 6bits? ( my example was 1 byte and 4bits)

Answer (score 0):

```
byte b1 = 0xAB;
byte b2 = 0xCD;
...
short s = (short)(b1<<8) | ((short)(b2<<4) & 0xF0);
//s = ABC0
```

Use or(|) instead of and (&) to merge the shifted values together otherwise always 0.

Comment: should be `b2<<4` not 8